# How to internationalize the UITextField placeholder property value string in interface builder itself?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

How can we internationalize the placeholder property's value of a UITextField  in interface builder-attribute inspector?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do the same localization as usual:

```
    myTextField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"emptyUsername",
@"userNameTextFieldPlaceholder");
```

Then you enter the according string in your localizable strings file.

The question has been discussed here, too:
[How to use NSLocalizedString in IB [iPhone SDK]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094233/how-to-use-nslocalizedstring-in-ib-iphone-sdk)

Describing an alternative, using several xib files.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I missed an important thing in my question. I want to know how to do this in interface builder-attribute inspector. Anyhow thanks for your help.

Answer (score 12):

You can easily change it without writing any code.
here is the example in your localized strings file set your placeholder as follows

"itw-s8-fkt.placeholder" = "YOUR TEXT";

Comment: Worked like charm (in localisation file)

Answer (score 1):

What I've done, to minimise the amount of localisation boilerplate, is follow the model outlined [here](https://medium.com/@mario.negro.martin/easy-xib-and-storyboard-localization-b2794c69c9db) (GitHub [here](https://github.com/emenegro/xib-localization)): create Interface Builder-friendly helper extensions (`@IBInspectable` vars, in a single file for convenience) for all the types of controls I want localised, including one for `UITextField` placeholders.  I can then centralise all localisations to a single `.strings` file for each language and hook them up via IB.  The only downside is remembering to add the keys when I create the controls.  Localisation debugging (set by editing the Run scheme; I run the app in a non-base language by default) helps spot these early.

I have a single Excel spreadsheet containing keys and translations that gets passed to local translators to update, and a script that (re)generates the `.strings` files from the `.csv` prior to release.

With reference to the linked tutorial, my `UITextField` extension looks like this:

```
extension UITextField: XIBLocalizable {
    @IBInspectable var xibLocKey: String? {
        get { return nil }
        set(key) {
            text = key?.localized
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var xibPlaceholder: String? {
        get { return nil }
        set(key) {
            placeholder = key?.localized
        }
    }
}
```

(The linked GitHub has an almost identical version I've only just spotted). Worth noting that when adding a new localisation I have to manually delete the contents of the XCode autogenerated `.strings` file, while leaving the file in place, to ensure the extensions get called.

Comment: The UITextView placeholder doesn't work for me, it says `Use of unresolved identifier 'placeholder'`